# QWebEngineView causes window to move slow

Tags: c++, qt

m trying to move my QMainWindow by using another widget inside QMainWindow.

Im moving my window by overriding :

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
```

in a QTabWidget. The window moves well and everything works fine if there is no QWebEngineView widget,  but if add the QWebEngineView widget to a layout the movement of the window is laggy, any idea?

here is a minimal reproducible example:

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

class MyTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    MyTabWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QTabWidget(parent){}
    protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
        pressPoint = event->pos();
    }
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
        this->window()->move(this->window()->pos() + (event->pos() - pressPoint) );
    }

    private:
        QPoint pressPoint;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWebEngineView>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MyTabWidget *tabWidget = new MyTabWidget(this);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tabWidget);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
    QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(this);
    widget->setLayout(hlayout);
    hlayout->addWidget(view);


    tabWidget->addTab(widget, "asd");
    view->load(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"));


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

In this code if you delete everything related to QWebEngineView the window will move without lag.

**Edit:**

[this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop) does the job but , is there a better way to do this?

```
setUpdatesEnabled(false); //This in mousePressEvent
bigVisualChanges();
setUpdatesEnabled(true); //This in mouseReleaseEvent
```

i dont like this way because for example if im watching a youtube video the image will freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reimplement your `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent` this way, with `globalPosition()` instead of `pos()`. Worked for me. Window started to move smoothly.

```cpp
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
{
    pressPoint = event->globalPosition().toPoint();
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override
{
    QPoint delta = event->globalPosition().toPoint() - pressPoint;
    this->window()->move(this->window()->pos() + delta );
    pressPoint = event->globalPosition().toPoint();
    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

**Update**: For better web engine performance (page loading, video playing and webpage animations), build in release configuration.

**Update2**: test show https://youtu.be/QM3UXjipr8Q.

Comment: this does help with the smoothness but when playing a video the window moves slowly

Comment: @Franco tell please, what is your build configuration? Is it debug or release? If it is debug, try to build and run in release mode. I built in release configuration, and it started to work much better.

Comment: its release, the problem is not that is super slow, the problem is that the window flickers

Comment: @Franco sorry, can't reproduce any more flickering then. May be it's OS feature or Qt version, I work on Windows 10 on latest Qt 6.4-beta. Does it flicker when you move the window by it's frame or header?

Comment: i changed the code using your idea and certainly it made the window to move smooth but if i play a video the window doesnt look that smooth, maybe its something related to the QWebEngineView widget, i will accept your answer because actually helped me with the smoothness